# Finding bracket score for given string

Tags: java, algorithm

Given string having brackets made of characters `(` and `)`

Find the positions `s[i] = '(' and s[j] = ')'` such that `i < j`, calculate its score as `(j-i)`. A position can be chosen only once for calculating score. Find the maximum possible score.

**Constraints:**
Size of string is `1 to 10^5`

**Example:**

```
String = "()()"
```

**Answer:**

```
3
```

**Explanation:**

*Option 1:*

```
s[0] = '(' and s[1] = ')' so score = 1-0 = 1. Next s[2] = '(' and s[3] = ')' score = 1 + (3-2) = 1 + (1) = 2
```

*Option 2:*

```
s[0] = '(' and s[3] = ')' so score = 3-0 = 3.
```

So `3` is the maximum score.

This is a in hackerrank question asked in interview some days back.

This is my idea to solve this problem.

Using a for loop, i from 0 and j from end position.

Find the first occurrence of '(' using i, then find the first occurrence of ')' using j in reverse direction.

Find the score (j-i) add that score to result. Break the loop if i exceeds j. So my approach takes O(n) time.

When I used this approach in hackerrank, 5 test cases are failing out of 15. The failing testcases are due to in-correct output, also the input strings are of size 10^5

I am not able to find out where I went wrong. What is the correct way to solve this problem?

**Update:**

This is my code:

```
public long solve(String s) {
    long score = 0;
    int n = s.length();
    for(int i=0, j=n-1; i<j;) {
        char c = s.charAt(i), d = s.charAt(j);
        while(c != '(') {
            i++;
            if(i < j && i<n) c = s.charAt(i);
        }
        while(d != '(') {
            j--;
            if(i < j) d = s.charAt(j);
        }
        score += (j-i);
    }
    return score;
}
```

Comment: *`I am not able to find out where I went wrong.`*  Nor can we without seeing your complete code, properly formatted, as a [mre].   I also noticed you don't have the **informed** badge.  So please take the time to take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: You've only accounted for *Option 2* producing the maximum score. You're probably failing the 5 test cases due to *Option 1* producing the maximum score.